# Is this miswak (tooth stick) method from authentic sunnah?

Tags: fiqh, sunnah, taharah, bidah

I was watching this [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZD0_d5upgYM) from the founder of [Dawateislami](https://www.dawateislami.net/). There are some things which are new to me about the use of miswak (tooth stick):

1. Miswak shouldn't be longer than a hand-span as it will cause Satan to sit on it [0:22]
2. One should not clinch with the fist as it will cause piles [0:37]
3. While washing miswak, recite salawat or better to include "Ya Qadir" [0:47]

**Question:** Are these practices from the authentic sunnah?